# How to define a base class in a seperate file than the header file and not throw a "base class undefined" error?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, header-files

Edit: I have found my problem, even through I asked a crappy question, I found circular inclusion and fixed it.

I am getting a strange error: `error C2504: 'CUpdatable' : base class undefined`. It is strange be cause in my code I have included both the base class header file, and even have the class prototype. Here are all of the relevant pieces of code:

In CRoom.h

```
    #ifndef CROOM_H
    #define CROOM_H

    #include "CUpdatable.h"

    class CUpdatable;

    class CRoom : public CUpdatable // <-- error here "CUpdatable is undefined"
    {
            ...
    }

    #endif
```

In CRoom.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "CRoom.h"

    CRoom:: // ...
    // etc
```

In CUpdatable.h

```
    #ifndef CUPDATABLE_H
    #define CUPDATABLE_H

    class CUpdatable
    {
            ...
    }

    #endif
```

In CUpdatable.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

    CUpdatable:: // ...
    // etc
```

My first guess was to include the class prototype `class CUpdatable;` within CRoom.h, but that has not worked.

What looks like is happening is that the header files are not seeing the .cpp files at compile time, so CUpdatable does not have definitions at that point, and throws this error. So how do you fix this?

Comment: Does your actual code have missing semicolons after the class definitions?

Comment: Are you sure your #include guards are as shown? Since your semicolons are missing I don't think you are posting the actual code.

Comment: If you're including `"CUpdatable.h"` in `CRoom.h`, there should be no need to forward declare `class CUpdatable` --- the entire definition would be visible already.  If removing the forward declaration causes an error that `CUpdatable` is not a class, check that your inclusion is working.  (And, of course, as has already been mentioned, the missing semicolons after the class definitions should be triggering any number of weird errors.)  Also, why isn't `CUpdatable.h` being included in `CUpdatable.cpp`?  You should probably post a self-contained compilable program demonstrating the problem.